# How to get sum of elements in nested json using scala?

Tags: list, scala, collections

I am using scala to process nested json

```
"disks" : [ {
"name" : "v2.16",
"diskAggregate" : "aggr0",
"diskRPM" : 15000,
"totalSizeBytes" : 1077477376,
"vendorId" : "NETAPP  ",
"usedBytes" : 1070071808,
"diskType" : "FCAL",
"uuid" : "4E455441:50502020:56442D31:3030304D:422D465A:2D353230:32353836:30303030:00000000:00000000",
"portName" : "FC:A ",
"raidGroup" : "rg0"
}, 
{
"name" : "v4.16",
"diskAggregate" : "aggr0",
"diskRPM" : 15000,
"totalSizeBytes" : 1077477376,
"vendorId" : "NETAPP  ",
"usedBytes" : 1070071808,
"diskType" : "FCAL",
"uuid" : "4E455441:50502020:56442D31:3030304D:422D465A:2D353230:32353633:34333030:00000000:00000000",
"portName" : "FC:B ",
"raidGroup" : "rg0"
}]
```

I want to get sum of 'usedBytes' in all json object of json array.
How do I get sum of 'usedBytes' from above json using scala??

**EDIT:**

Here is what I tried

```
val datastoreCapacity = disks
val usableSpace = datastoreCapacity.foldLeft(0L) {
case (sumOfUsedSpace, esxDevice) =>
  val sumOfTotalBytesOnStorageDevice = esxDevice.datastores.foldLeft(0L) {
    case (totalBytesOnDevice, datastore) =>
     // totalBytesOnDevice + ut..getOrElse(0L).toString.toLong
    val sum = datastore.utilization.foldLeft(0L) {
      case (total,util) =>
        total + util.usedBytes.getOrElse(0L).toString.toLong
    }
  }
  sumOfUsedSpace + sumOfTotalBytesOnStorageDevice
 }
```

Comment: Is `usedBytes` property a string or a long? If a string, the make the code that read `getOrElse(0L).toString` into `getOrElse("0")`. By the way, what is the result of your algorithm. It looks generally what you need.

Comment: @bob usedBytes is long

Comment: Its not giving me sum .. it gives error as expected 'Long' found 'unit'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the foldLeft (B) below, the last expression is an assignment (commented out), which returns Unit.

```
val datastoreCapacity = disks
val usableSpace = datastoreCapacity.foldLeft(0L) { // A

    case (sumOfUsedSpace, esxDevice) =>
         val sumOfTotalBytesOnStorageDevice = esxDevice.datastores.foldLeft(0L) { // B

             case (totalBytesOnDevice, datastore) =>
                   // totalBytesOnDevice + ut..getOrElse(0L).toString.toLong
                   /* Note --> val sum = */ // assignment returns Unit
                   datastore.utilization.foldLeft(0L) { // C

                       case (total,util) =>
                            total + util.usedBytes.getOrElse(0L).toString.toLong
                   }

         }
         sumOfUsedSpace + sumOfTotalBytesOnStorageDevice
}
```